# Create std::vector<py::handle> in C++ with pybind11

Tags: c++, pybind11

I'm trying to create a `std::vector<py::handle>` in C++ to unittest a C++ function that receives such a vector. I need to create a vector of integers (`py::int_`), floats (`py::float_`) and strings (`py::str`).

I've tried things like:

```
  auto int1 = py::int_(1);
  std::vector<py::handle> values = {py::handle(int1)};
```

Or:

```
  auto int1 = py::int_(1);
  std::vector<py::handle> values = {py::handle(int1.ptr())};
```

But this always SIGSEVs.

I'm new to pybind11, so I'm probably doing something very obviously wrong. Any idea how to do it? I couldn't find an obvious way in the docs.

Comment: So it works in the function but not in the test?

Comment: There's actually something very wrong. Because even a single line: `auto int1 = py::int_(1);` breaks. There must be something wrong in the compilation setup. I'll try to figure that out. It didn't break when I starting writing this. But now it breaks. I'm maybe too tired already. Can't trust my senses since that makes no sense.

Comment: My explanation should have included all the rest of the code around that portion that failed, because the problem was that I wasn't initializing an interpreter, and people reading this couldn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I needed to add a:

```
py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
```

At the beginning of each test.

**Why?:**
Because I never ran the C++ code from the interpreter, but was purely testing the C++ code. So I needed to start a Python interpreter from C++ to be able to use `py::` features.